# Delete MongoDB-document by its string-ID

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, uniqueidentifier

I have a MongoDB-document that looks like this:

```json
{
    _id: 'EXISTING_ID'
}
```

I want to delete this document and I tried to use this code to do so (leveraging the native node-js driver for MongoDB):

```js
import { MongoClient, ObjectId } from "mongodb";

export const deleteDocumentWithId = (id: string) => {
  return MongoClient.connect(dbUrl, (err, db) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }

    const dbo = db.db("my-db");

    dbo.collection("my-collection").deleteOne({ _id: id }, (err, obj) => {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      db.close();
    });
  });
};

deleteDocumentWithId("EXISTING_ID");
```

however, the TypeScript-compiler throws an error, saying that no overloads match this call; `_id` should rather be of type `ObjectId`. However, if I replace the call with:

```js
dbo.collection("my-collection").deleteOne({ _id: new ObjectId(id) }...
```

I get a runtime error, saying:

```
BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
```

because the string "EXISTING_ID" is only 11 bytes in size.

However, I don't even think, that `ObjectId` is the right type to use here, as I don't see  `ObjectId` in the database. The `_id` for the document above is a string.

In Java, there are the methods `findById` or `deleteById`, but I don't see these in NodeJS. Is there a way to achieve what I want, that I just haven't found yet?

Comment: Define `IdType` as string. See https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.0/modules.html#inferidtype

Comment: @Alex-Blex thanks for your comment! Could you formulate that into an answer for me to accept? Also, can you include how this would apply to the code I showed above? I can’t really make sense of the documentation you linked to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify type of `_id` field used in "my-collection". The [Filter](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.0/modules.html#filter) type of the `deleteOne` parameter uses [InferIdType](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.0/modules.html#inferidtype) which is ObjectId by default.

At least inline:

```
dbo.collection<{_id: string}>("my-collection").deleteOne({ _id: id }, (err, obj) => {
```

but honestly, if you are using typescript you'd better have the proper named type for objects in "my-collection".