# Define MongoDB _id-Type as String

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, documentation, uniqueidentifier

I want to delete the following document from my database:

```json
{
    _id: 'EXISTING_ID'
}
```

As you can see, the `_id` is defined as a string, rather than `ObjectId`. This makes deletion difficult, since I can't use the following code (leveraging the native MongoDB-driver for node.js):

```js
export const deleteDocumentWithId = (id: string) => {
  return MongoClient.connect(dbUrl, (err, db) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }

    const dbo = db.db("my-db");

    dbo.collection("my-collection").deleteOne({ _id: id }, (err, obj) => {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      db.close();
    });
  });
};

deleteDocumentWithId("EXISTING_ID");
```

In [a related question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70353024/delete-mongodb-document-by-its-string-id), a user commented to define `_id` as string and linked to [this part of the documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.0/modules.html#inferidtype). However, I don't see `InferIdType` to be helpful here, because it only yields the type of `_id` of the passed in type:

```js
import {InferIdType} from "mongodb";

type obj = {
  _id: string;
};

const foo: InferIdType<obj> = undefined; // foo is of type string
```

How can I define `_id` to be of type string here?

Comment: `db.collection.deleteOne( { _id: 'EXISTING_ID' } )`- this command from the `mongo` shell deletes the document (you had posted) from the collection.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! However, that doesn't help much, because I have to use node.js for my use-case.

Comment: I see that you are specifying the `deleteDocumentWithId` function parameter `id` of type `ObjectId` - is it not a `string` type you want?

Comment: Copy-paste-error. sorry. I edited the question.

Comment: I answered the original question. I appreciate it must be confusing and may be even frustrating but there is no really need to multiply questions beyond necessity.  Please respect SO policies against duplicates and delete this one.  Try to learn Mongo+Typescript from simpler examples, e.g. start from https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/typescript/ to understand the basic concepts.

Comment: I don't have any problems with MongoDB or TypeScript, but you confused me, when you linked to InferIdType (which is a valid confusion, because it doesn't relate directly to the question). Regarding the new question: I got a step further with your comment and redefined the question statement. Of course the two questions handle the same problem (from my perspective), but with a different questioning. That's why I regarded it as ok to open this question. Please correct me, if I'm wrong here!

Comment: Yes, I admit my comment was rather short, sorry about that. I assumed the code linked to the documentation is self-explanatory, and there is no point to provide full answer - just give a direction where to look.  I agree this question is not a total dupe, otherwise I'd closed it myself. I just asked you to make this decision - if you expect any better answer here - you are welcome to keep it open. Otherwise I'd recommend to delete it.